# Comala/Confluence - Cause Trigger when Worfklow First Applied

Tags: confluence

I have a trigger in my workflow to set permissions when a page goes to the "In Progress" state.

```
{trigger:statechanged|state=In Progress}
    {set-restrictions:type=edit|group=Managers}
{trigger}
```

However, the first point at which the page is even managed by the workflow is when I hit "Add workflow", upon which the state is "In Progress". However, it doesn't seem like the trigger is firing when I add the workflow. So I'd have to publish, and then put it back to in progress.

A workaround would be to add an initial state (called "Warning: No permission restrictions!", for example), and then you'd move from that to "In Progress" so that there's always a trigger.

But is there a way to apply those permissions when I simply apply the workflow for the first time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, if you update the Comala Workflow version to 6.4.1, the event would be automatically triggered.

According to Comala Workflows 6.4.1 https://wiki.comalatech.com/display/CWL/Triggers#Triggers-Event-specificfilters, the very first state would be considered as an "initial" state. And the event would be automatically triggered once an initial state has been given as the state.

So you don't need to change any of your markup scripts, once you have updated to the new version, the trigger would work as you expected.

However, with an older version, you can also just specify "initial" because, in versions like "5.2" for example, the default value for "initial has been set to false.
[image]

```
{trigger:statechanged|state=In Prograss|initial=true}
    {set-restrictions:type=edit|group=Managers}
{trigger}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I think since I posted this I did get the behavior to work, by default as you mentioned. Great to see another Comala markup user around here!